# trying to reinstall ca-certs on centos

Tags: centos, ssl, yum

I am trying to connect to a web service and i get an error:

```
cURL error 77: .........
```

I have read all over the web, that i can fix it by:

```
yum reinstall -y ca-certificates
```

but when i do that, i get:

```
# yum reinstall -y ca-certificates
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Determining fastest mirrors
Could not get metalink https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-7&arch=x86_64 error was
14: curl#77 - "Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)"
Could not retrieve mirrorlist https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/x86_64/mirrorlist error was
14: curl#77 - "Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)"
```

What do i need to do?

Comment: Explaining that `-y` option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209361/whats-the-difference-between-yum-y-install-and-yum-install-in-centos

Answer (score 3):

You temporary disable verifying ssl in yum with the following.

1. ```
   echo "sslverify=0" >> /etc/yum.conf
   ```
2. yum reinstall -y ca-certificates
3. Remove temporary hack with editor of your choice from /etc/yum.conf

### Edit:

If for some reason, this still doesn't work, you might try the following:

1. Find the package. In the case of RPM packages, I recommend the following website - https://pkgs.org/
2. Download package with `curl -k` or `wget --no-check-certificate`. Note that case below I'm using `http` but there might be redirection to https. In case of CentOS 7 and **curent date** it will look like: `wget --no-check-certificate http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/ca-certificates-2020.2.41-70.0.el7_8.noarch.rpm || curl -k http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/ca-certificates-2020.2.41-70.0.el7_8.noarch.rpm -o ca-certificates-2020.2.41-70.0.el7_8.noarch.rpm`
3. Install it manually with `yum reinstall -y ./ca-certificates-2020.2.41-70.0.el7_8.noarch.rpm`

Comment: I tried that and got same result.

Comment: @bart2puck see edit